# How can i remove from a jsonb all elements with value is null?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a table "points" and the columns "node_id", "tags", etc.

How can i remove from the jsonb element "tags" all elements with the null value ?

```json
{
  "addInfo": {
    "payment": {
      "payment:dkv": null,
      "payment:uta": null,
    },
    "fueltype": {
      "fuel:diesel": "yes",
      "fuel:octane_91": null,
      "fuel:octane_95": "yes",
      "fuel:octane_98": null
    },
    "operating": {
      "name": "Raiffeisen",
      "brand": "Raiffeisen",
      "operator": null,
      "opening_hours": "24/7"
    }
  }
}
```

i want to get this form:

```json
{
  "addInfo": {
    "payment": {},
    "fueltype": {
      "fuel:diesel": "yes",
      "fuel:octane_95": "yes"
    },
    "operating": {
      "name": "Raiffeisen",
      "brand": "Raiffeisen",
      "opening_hours": "24/7"
    }
  }
}
```

I try until with this example code, it works but is not smart. I use twice jsonb_strip_nulls and replace and convert between text and jsonb. Is any other way to get the same smarter ?

```sql
SELECT node_id,
       nullif(jsonb_strip_nulls(replace("addInfo" ::text, '{}', 'null')
                                ::jsonb) ::text,
              '{}') ::jsonb
  FROM (SELECT jsonb_strip_nulls(
                 jsonb_build_object('addInfo',
                                     jsonb_build_object('EXAMPLE....'))) "addInfo"
          FROM points p
         WHERE p.tags notnull
           AND p.tags - >> 'amenity' = 'fuel') foo;
```

And how can i have the original sorting:

```
1 operating
2 payment
3 fueltype
```

Answer (score 7):

`json_strip_nulls` and `jsonb_strip_nulls` this functions deletes all object fields that have null values from the given JSON value. Null values that are not object fields are untouched. **The best side of these functions is that they are recursive, so the function will be deleted null values in sub JSON objects too.**

**ATTENTION!!!** - your JSON string code has invalid, I removed one `,` character in your JSON and commented on this.

```
select jsonb_strip_nulls(
'{
    "addInfo": {
        "payment": {
            "payment:dkv": null,
            "payment:uta": null   /* in here I removed character: "," */
        },
        "fueltype": {
            "fuel:diesel": "yes",
            "fuel:octane_91": null,
            "fuel:octane_95": "yes",
            "fuel:octane_98": null
        },
        "operating": {
            "name": "Raiffeisen",
            "brand": "Raiffeisen",
            "operator": null,
            "opening_hours": "24/7"
        }
    }
}')
```

Works fine!!! Result:

```json
{
  "addInfo": {
    "payment": {},
    "fueltype": {
      "fuel:diesel": "yes",
      "fuel:octane_95": "yes"
    },
    "operating": {
      "name": "Raiffeisen",
      "brand": "Raiffeisen",
      "opening_hours": "24/7"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is a possibility to delete all the empty objects {} also ?

Comment: jsonb_strip_nulls - this function removes only null values, But I wrote a sample recursive function for removing null and empty objects. You can see this sample from my GitHub profile:  https://github.com/raminfaracov/PostgreSQL-json-examples/blob/main/remove_null_empty_objects_from_json.sql

Comment: i need a schema exmples ? should  be there some data ?

Comment: Here is samples data:  https://github.com/raminfaracov/PostgreSQL-json-examples/blob/main/sample_data.sql  - and for viewing result data you can see result.json file